# KNN search with signed metrics

Tags: c++, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am looking for a C++ library that allows to efficiently find the k-nearest neighbors of a point in a point set, using the squared pseudo norm :
[image]

where my third coordinate may or may not have a minus sign in its squared norm. Alternatively, I can consider a 4D space where the third component always has positive sign and the fourth one always a negative sign.

The documentation of the ANN library states that it can use any "Minkowski" metric. The metric above is the definition of a Minkowski metric (in the sense of [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiMetric.html) , but not in ANN's sense). However, ANN seems flexible and only seems to require a "+" and "-" operator ([ANN documentation](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ANNmanual_1.1.pdf), page 14), but they are not defined per component but globally.

Has anyone ever generalized ANN to handle such a case ? Is-it trivial ? Doesn't it screw up the kd-tree ? Does another library exist for that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Would the one who voted to close the question for the "not constructive" reason elaborate ? My question is targeted, has not been previously posed, and would benefit the community. I'd be happy to edit my question if specific comments are made, but a single "close" vote doesn't help much. For instance, would removing the "c++" tag and asking whether a Minkoski metric is properly handled by a Kd-tree structure be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>-z<sup>2</sup> violates some assumptions a search using a kd-tree is usually based on. One of these assumption is that 'neighborhood' ('being close') is some 'local' property, i.e. given a point P all points Q with `dist(P,Q) < r` have coordinates in a finite range around the coordinates of P. Thus splitting the point set along their coordinates can be exploited for an efficient search. But for the above norm even for the points Q with `dist([0,0,0],Q) = 0` no finite box can be given; the points lie on an infinite cone. Still it should be possible to design an efficient search algorithm that exploits the 'cone'-structure - but a kd-tree will not work.